# JavaScript sleep function sequence?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was making a discord bot with JavaScript. I'd like to make cooltime when player works bot.

First, I set waiting function.

```js
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));
}
```

And,

```
if (mine_cooltime === 0) {
    mine_cooltime = 1;

    const msgRef = await message.reply({embeds: [embed_mine_stone]}); // Don't care this

    sleep(user.mine_time)
    .then(() => msgRef.edit({embeds: [embed_mine_stone_end]})) // Don't care this
    .then(() => saveUser = {id, name, wood : user.wood, stone : user.stone + 3, iron : user.iron, coal : user.coal, gold : user.gold, diamond : user.diamond,
        findWood : user.findWood, findStone : 1, findironOre : user.findironOre, findCoal : user.findCoal, findGold : user.findGold, findDiamond : user.findDiamond, user.mine_time : user.mine_time
        })
    .then(() => fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(saveUser)))
    .then(() => mine_cooltime = 0);
}
```

This is a code which mines stones.

```js
if (wood_cooltime === 0) {
    wood_cooltime = 1;

    const msgRef = await message.reply({embeds: [embed_wood_cut]}); // Don't care this
    sleep(user.wood_time)
    .then(() => msgRef.edit({embeds: [embed_wood_cut_end]})) // Don't care this
    .then(() => saveUser = {id, name, wood : user.wood + 5, stone : user.stone, iron : user.iron, coal : user.coal, gold : user.gold, diamond : user.diamond,
        findWood : 1, findStone : user.findStone, findironOre : user.findironOre, findCoal : user.findCoal, findGold : user.findGold, findDiamond : user.findDiamond, user.mine_time : user.mine_time
        })
    .then(() => fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(saveUser)))
    .then(() => wood_cooltime = 0);
}
```

And this is a code which cuts woods.

Both "mine_time" and "wood_time" are 5000.

If I operate mining code 3 seconds after operate cutting code, At first 2 seconds after mining code were finished, "wood" was increased. But when mining code finished, 'wood" was same and only "stone" was increased.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You update `saveUser` with the value from `user` and write `saveUser` to a file, but did you update `user`? If you didn't update `user`, you are reusing the oldest values whenever you try to update `saveUser`.

Comment: Side note: it is redundant to have every single line each in a separate `then` block. If the tasks to be done in the `then` blocks are not asynchronous, just do all of them in one `then` block. Or simply just use async/await

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you assign the modified user object to `saveUser`, which means `user` still has the old values. So if a few seconds later the other code also creates a modified object, it will make the modification from the original object, and not from the modified version.

I would suggest to forget about the `saveUser` variable and just assign to `user`, and use that in `JSON.stringify` as well.

Maybe you need the user object to be immutable, but if this is not a requirement, you don't even need to create an entirely new object with an object literal. Instead, you could just mutate the existing object with `user.wood += 5` and `user.stone += 3`. But again, this will mutate the user object, which maybe will not work with your state management framework.